# How do I find all collections with a certain string in the name in my MongoDB database?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I've got a database containing several collections. Some has got a name like "carpenter_title_year_version". Others has got a name like "plumber_title_year_version". How do I set up a filter to retrieve all collections where the string "carpenter" is in the collectionname?

I'm thinking something like:

```
       var filterBuilder = Builders<GroupEntity>.Filter;
        var projectionBuilder = Builders<GroupEntity>.Projection;
        var collection = Database.GetCollection<GroupEntity>("dbname");
        var filter = filterBuilder.ElemMatch("carpenter..., ?"); //<--- ???
        var projection = projectionBuilder.Exclude("_id");
        var list = await collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Code and description don't match. Looks like you have a single collection called `dbname`, and arrays named `carpenter` in your strongly typed items of type `GroupEntity`. Did you actually try this code out?

Comment: No, this code does not work.

The database is called "dbname" in this case. It contains collections with different names (like "carpenter_titel_year_version". Im interested in listing the collectionnames, not actually retrieving the documents in those). I need to build a list of all collections belonging to the "carpenters", and those have the string "carpenter" as part of the collectionname.

Comment: You should remove that code. It has no relevance whatsoever to what you want to do. It confused me. It looks like you mixup collections for databases

Comment: That may very well be true...

Answer (score 0):

There's (and an async version of it)

```
IAsyncCursor<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> IMongoDatabase.ListCollections(ListCollectionsOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
```

You can use the filter from the collection options to match the collection name.

```
  // <CAPS INSIDE> are wildcards
  var _client = new MongoClient(@"connection string");
  var _database = _client.GetDatabase("<DATABASE NAME>");
  var bre = new BsonRegularExpression("<YOUR REGEX PATTERN>");
  var copt = new ListCollectionsOptions{ Filter = 
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex ("name", bre )
  };
  var collectionsWithMatchingNames = _database.ListCollections(copt).ToList().Select (col => col["name"]);
```

Only then you get your particular collection, like:

```
foreach (var x in collectionsWithMatchingNames)
     var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(x);
```

Comment: This looks more like it! Thanks a lot!